# How to use a keyboard shortcut to raise application from system tray

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, notification-area

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut to raise an application that is running in the system tray (keepassx).

I have tried xdotool but it does not work.  xdotool finds the windows that match the app name but activatewindow gives an error (XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)) my guess is that the application does not have a window to activate.

I also tried wmctrl with similar results, in this case no window is found.

Any ideas of what I can do?

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS - LXDE / Openbox

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you ever find a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with kde:

I assigned shortcut to my tray icon application.  To raise it from tray by command I use: xdotool key "my shortcut"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Tried both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` but they don't seem to work with a window hidden in system tray.

I solved it with simple `bash -c "pkill keepassx && keepassx"`. For this to work *Start minimized* need to be unchecked. Used with KeePassX 0.4.3 .